# How to reference internal delegate of a different assembly in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

I have following code

```
public class MyClass{
     internal static Dictionary<string, ActivityManager.TagSerializer> TagHandlers = new Dictionary<string, ActivityManager.TagSerializer>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

where TagSerializer is a delegate in ActivityManager like following

```
public class ActivityManager
{ internal delegate string TagSerializer(string tag, ActivityTemplateVariable atv, ContentType ct, CultureInfo ci);}
```

Because myclass and ActivityManager are in different assembly, my code will return error

> Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary
>   <string,Microsoft.Office.Server.ActivityFeed.ActivityManager.TagSerializer>' is less accessible than field 'MyClass.TagHandlers'

ActivityManager class is in a third party assembly, and I can't change it.

How do I use reflection to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx).

Comment: I can't change the ActivityManager class, it is a third party assembly

Comment: I'm not sure that is the case when using Reflection.

Comment: I mean I can't change anything in the third party assembly where ActivityManager lives